# Covariance of cells in random contingency tables

Tags: chi-squared-test, covariance, contingency-tables

Say we have $n=3$ bins and $m=3$ different coloured balls (30 red 20 green and 50 blue) in an urn. We draw randomly without replacement a ball from from the urn and place it into the bins. The first 25 go into the first bin, the second 25 go into the second bin, the last 50 go into the last bin.

This gives a contingency table

$$\begin{array}{ccc|l}
    x_{11}    & x_{12}  &  x_{13}& R_1 \quad\text{red}\\ 
    x_{21}   & x_{22}   & x_{23}& R_2  \quad\text{green}\\ 
    x_{31}   & x_{32}   & x_{33}& R_3 \quad\text{blue}  \\  \hline
    C_1    &  C_2  & C_3  & N \\
    \text{bin 1}    &  \text{bin 2}  & \text{bin 3}   \\
\end{array}$$

that could, in our example, have for instance values like

$$\begin{array}{ccc|c}
    7    & 8  &  15& 30 \\ 
    4   & 5   & 11& 20  \\ 
    14  &  12  & 24& 50  \\  \hline
    25   &  25  & 50  & 100 \\
\end{array}$$

**Question:**

What is the covariance between the nine different $x_{ij}$?

And more generally what is the answer/formula for any random contingency table like this with $n>2$ and/or $m>2$, and any values of the row and column totals $R_i$ and $C_i$

Comment: Special cases for smaller values of $m$ and $n$. When $n=2$ and $m=2$, then we have a hypergeometric distribution. When $n=1$ or $m=1$, the we have a multinomial distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The distribution of the cells in the same row or same column of the contingency table are similar to a [multivariate hypergeometric distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#Multivariate_hypergeometric_distribution).

The Variance is

$$Var(x_{ij}) = \frac{R_i(N-R_1){C_j}(N- {C_j})}{N^2(N-1)} $$

The correlation for cells in the same row $i$ is

$$Cor(x_{ij},x_{ik}) = - \sqrt{\frac{C_jC_k}{(N-C_j)(N-C_k)}} \quad \text{if $j\neq k$}$$

The correlation for cells in the same column $i$ is

$$Cor(x_{ji},x_{ki}) = - \sqrt{\frac{R_jR_k}{(N-R_j)(N-R_k)}}\quad  \text{if $j\neq k$}$$

The correlation for cells with a different column and row is

$$Cor(x_{ji},x_{kl}) = \dots \quad  \text{if $j\neq k$ and $i \neq l$}$$

This one I can not solve yet.